# Bindable data source with arbitary number of columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I need to display data with a fixed number of rows and a user changeable number of columns (time series of data). I'm not sure what type I should use as a data source. A 2d array is [possible](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/BindArrayGrid.aspx), but I'd prefer something fully supported by .NET Framework.

Comment: If its going to be user changeable, it maybe easier to create an extension of the datagridview which supports adding/deleting columns via an internal datatable.

Comment: @nEm  that seems like overkill.  The data set is small enough and expected changes infrequent enough that simply recreating it with each change shouldn't have any performance issues.

Comment: It wasn't as bad when I did it for my project. When you extend you have all the functionalities from DataGridView anyways, and I just added an internal dataTable (in my case I used a 2d array since that is what I needed) and just one method that filled the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about datatable. I think that is more flexible when your columns are changing and rows are going to be same.